# In the Facebook share button code, what is the <meta name="medium" content="mult">?

Tags: facebook

I know Facebook is trying to phase out the Share button, but the product management still wants to use it, so I see every where the code can be

```
<fb:share-button class="meta">
<meta name="medium" content="mult"/>
<meta name="title" content="name of fan page"/>
<meta name="description" content="description of fan page"/>
<link rel="image_src" href="url to image location" />
<link rel="target_url" href="http://..."/>
</fb:share-button>
```

but no where can I find what `mult` is in the line `<meta name="medium" content="mult"/>`.  Does anybody know what `mult` is and alternatives there are?

Answer (score 0):

Mult stays for multimedia alternative your can use Video , and some other. If you have video on the page the tag video list your in the search engine as video page